# Convert this function from jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have this function in jQuery

```
$('.cancelPending').live('click', function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('opacity')){ return false; }
    $(this).addClass('opacity').html('<i class="icon icon-remove"></i>Cancelling...');
    var id = $(this).parents('.holiday').getId();
    //Etc...
```

How would I recreate that in Angular? So far I have just the empty function set up

```
<a class="cancelPending" ng-click="cancePending(p.id)" href="#"><i class="icon icon-remove"></i>Cancel Request</a>

...

$scope.cancelPending = function(id) {

}
```

What's the Angular way to manipulate the classes/html of an element? I think for the class it will be `ng-class="{opacity: someVariable?}"` but I can't think what the HTML would be.

Comment: It is with `ng-class` - you're right about that. Since your manipulating the DOM I would use a *directive* !

Comment: have you read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as tymeJV said, the "Angular way" manipulating the DOM is using directives.

**Example:**
html:

```
<div ng-app="App"  >
    <div cancel-Pending="" myid='5' ><i class="icon icon-remove"></i>Cancel Request</div>
</div>
```

directive:

```
    app.directive("cancelPending", [function () {
    var isFullScreen = false;

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            myid:'@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element,attr) {

              var el= $(element);
                  el.on('click', function(){
                if($(element).hasClass('opacity')){ return false; }
                el.addClass('opacity').html('<i class="icon icon-remove"></i>Cancelling...');
                    console.log(scope.myid); //5                          
               // var id = el.parents('.holiday').getId();
                //Etc...
              });


        }
    };
}]);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/5WxS2/1/